# group files after pathnames

Tags: java, shell

i am trying to write a jave code that does the following, but atm have no clue how to realize this:

let us say: i have 7 files in different or equal paths on local system, that i want to copy somewhere else using as few pathnames in my shell command as possible

correctfiles are the files i want, somefiles i do not care about

for instance i do not want :

```
copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12\correctfile3 && copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12\correctfile4
```

instead i want the Uberfolder whenever possible:

```
copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12\
```

and that demands that there is no somefile in copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12
because i do not want to transfer somefile

e.g.

C:\tmp\folder1: somefile1, somefile2

C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder11: correctfile1, correctfile2

C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12: correctfile3, correctfile4

C:\tmp\folder2\subfolder21: correctfile5

C:\tmp\folder2\subfolder22: correctfile6, correctfile7

so in this example i could use

```
copy C:\tmp\folder2
```

because alle files in that folder are correctfiles

and for the others i would have to

```
 copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder11
 copy C:\tmp\folder1\subfolder12
```

because there are somefiles in Uberfolder  C:\tmp\folder1 that i do not want to transfer

how could i achieve this?
a java class that sort of groups the files according to pathnames, using as few pathnames as possible

Comment: You do realize that factoring out and copying directories rather than contained individual files results in subtle (and possibly not so subtle) changes in the semantics and, as a result, in what and how data is actually copied?

Comment: yes, but for this task it is not as important, just trying to find out how this could be achieved theoretically

Comment: This seems like a pointless and complex optimization. [What is the purpose of the code?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: purpose is....i am creating a Bpel process with a transfer-activity(which only understands shell commands with pathnames) and i have to iterate over a list of pathnames that were given as parameters and one by one transfer the file in the current path to a remote computer with a for-loop. now i want to get rid of the forloop by grouping all pathnames into one pathname(when possible), otherwise group the pathnames to as few as possible pathnames in order to reduce the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite simple. From a `List<File> filesToCopy` create a

```
Map<String,Set<String>> dir2names = new HashMap<>();
for( File f: filesToCopy ){
    String name = f.getName();
    // test name for null and do error handling
    String dir = f.getParent();
    // dir for null and do error handling
    Set<String> names = dir2names.get( dir );
    if( names == null ){
        names = new HashSet<>();
        dir2names.put( dir, names );
    }
    names.add( name );
}
```

mapping the directory parts to file names. Iterate the keys of this map

```
for( String dirname: dir2names.keySet() ){
    File[] entries = new File( dirname ).listFiles();
    if( entries.length > dir2names.get( dirname ).size() ){
        // add list created from dirname + set of names to files to copy
        for( String name: dir2names.get( dirname ){
            String pathname = new File( dirname, name ).getAbsolutePath();
            // add pathname to files to copy
        }
    } else {
        // add directory identified by dirname to files to copy
    }
}
```

I don't think it is worth doing this recursively.

Comment: not sure i understand this, sorry quite a beginner here

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Stackoverflow isn't a programming service, and I have done more that just saying "show us your code", which is the customary response to questions such as yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. maybe i did not put it right, i did not demand a better or more understandable solution or something. just stated i am trying to understand your solution. i do not have a code yet, but a conceptual idea.

Comment: Providing this "conceptual idea" was the whole point of my answer :-)

Comment: I started with a List of File objects, which can easily created from a List of pathnames.

Comment: Elaborate on which part? Provide the connecttons, e.g., what do you have as input and what do you want to use as output to pass to the shell script? - It would be easier if the optimisation could be incrporated into existing code without the envisaged reduction.

Comment: I've added some more code. This is all very straightforward.

Comment: this would work for the first level of directories...if i wanted to group the directories further..i would have to use the function again on the results of the first function call....recursion, right_?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but the gain (= reduction of the number of pathnames you pass to the shell) will decrease - unless you *know* that the hierarchy is deep *and* you *know* that the first, second,... level almost *never* contain any files that shouldn't be copies.